# Break non-simple cycle to simple cycles?

Tags: graph-theory

Given a cycle, how can I break it into simple cycles? I know there are general DFS algorithms to find cycles. I want to know if there are any advantages I can use to simplify the calculation/algorithm, considering that this is already a cycle.

For example, I have the cycle below:

cycle_edges = [(4, 5), (3, 5), (2, 3), (2, 6), (6, 7), (7, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (8, 6), (4, 8), (4, 6), (6, 1), (1, 0), (0, 8), (4, 8)]
[image]

And I would like to break it into 5 simple cycles to [ [6, 5, 3, 2], [6, 5, 4], [6, 4, 7], [6, 4, 8], [6, 8, 0, 1]]

Answer (score 0):

You're starting with the cycle $453267456846108$ (I'm leaving the 4 at the end implicit, so we don't accidentally double-count it).

Look for any duplicate vertices in this cycle. For example, we have three $6$s. Now chop up the cycle (cyclically) into the cycles between those times we hit $6$. Here we get $6745$, $684$, and $61084532$ (looping around back to the start). These are simple because each has no duplicate vertices.

If you choose a different vertex to chop at, you could get different cycles. For example, cutting at $4$ gets you $453267$, $4568$, and $46108$.

If you want to get exactly those particular simple cycles you listed, this won't work, since the big starting cycle does not include a path $6\leftrightarrow 5 \leftrightarrow 3$.